# How to setResult from a resumed Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

My Android Application has the following functionality/flow.

**Scenario 1**

Activity A starts Activity B for result.

Activity B sets Result and finishes.

Activity A receives result in onActivityResult()

**Scenario 2**

Activity A starts Activity B for result.

Activity B starts Activity C

Activity C returns to B and finishes
 (Activity C has exclude from recents and no history true)

Activity B resumes then sets result and finishes

Activity A DOES NOT receive result in onActivityResult()

How can I get scenario 2 to complete with result as it does OK in scenario 1?

Comment: post the code , seems like a coding issue

Comment: As scenario 1 works fine. my issue must be caused by pausing Activity B while I display Activity C. All I need to know is... is it possible to Pause activity B, transition between C and have Activity B still set its result for activity A to detect?

Comment: yup , shouldn't be an issue